# Visualising changing rank-ordering when missing data is present

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I wish to visualise changes in relative rankings between categories through time, much like [this so-called 'subway-style' plot](http://jkunst.com/r/what-do-we-ask-in-stackoverflow/). However, not all categories are present in all time steps.

I have made a preliminary plot (see attached) that is sufficient to interpret the data (one simply needs to look at the crossing lines). However, because not every category is represented in every time slice, lines may traverse the y-axis without any change in rank, which is visually confusing:

[image: Changing rank-order plot with undesirable kinks]

Do algorithms exist for minimising the kinks in static ranks when missing data is present? To put it another way, my goal is to maintain straight lines wherever possible (when there is no change in relative rank).